# Is SetDlgItemDouble a C++ Function?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, c++98

I was looking at using SetDlgItemInt and out of curiosity I changed it to SetDlgItemDouble to see if this was also a function.

SetDlgItemDouble has been recognised as a function and when I hover over it, it displays `BOOL SetDlgItemDouble(HWND hDlg, int id, double d)` but when I go to compile it gives me the error: `error C3861: 'SetDlgItemDouble': identifier not found, even with argument-dependent lookup`.

I've googled the term SetDlgItemDouble and it gives me a few links mainly in a far east language but nothing directly with MSDN and also searching this site nothing comes back.

So is it a function? If so, how do I use it with visual c++ 2003?

Comment: `SetDlgItemDouble()` does not appear in [the list of dialog box functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468825(v=vs.85).aspx). I never heard about it myself. There is most probably no API with that name.

Comment: Looks like a homebrew implementation, that made it into your IntelliSense database. It's certainly not standard C++, nor is it a Windows API function. If it were, it'd be way too ambiguous. Given the parameters, there's no way to specify the width, or precision, or whether to use scientific notation. That's different from [`SetDlgItemInt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645518.aspx) (which **is** a Windows API call). The latter is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetDlgItemDouble` is **not** a *standard* C++ function: i.e. a standards compliant C++ compiler is not required to implement it.

But there's nothing stopping you from implementing it. Or a 3rd party library for that matter.

Your IDE is probably configured to think that the function exists, even if you don't have an explicit `#include` to the relevant file. Visual Studio does tend to do this (especially for standard C++ library functions that you haven't necessarily `#include`d), in order to attempt to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**SetDlgItemDouble** is not avaialble in MFC or win32. You can try using **SetDlgItemInt** (or) **SetDlgItemText** in visual c++. If the intention is to display a double value in any Dialog control, you can use SetDlgItemText and display that value as a string in your Dialog.